# Commenting multi-line command chains?

Tags: bash

I often have code where I format by making a long AND/OR statements. For example:

```
  # Get wifi router gateway
  gateway=$(cat $leases \
            | grep -A 5 -m 1 $wifi \
            | grep option\ routers \
            | cut -d' ' -f5 \
            | tr --delete \;)
```

Sometimes a single step in a command like above can be complex. Thus I end up wanting to comment it.

For example say the `cut` command was more complicated than it really is here. So I want to do something like:

```
  # Get wifi router gateway
  gateway=$(cat $leases \
            | grep -A 5 -m 1 $wifi \
            | grep option\ routers \
            # Here is a note
            | cut -d' ' -f5 \
            | tr --delete \;)
```

I realize this is invalid syntax.

But I'm curious to see if anyone else has some strategies for commenting long command chains?

Comment: Do you mean "add a comment", or "comment *out* the line"?

Comment: @JeffSchaller add comment like the part that says `# Here is a note`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work in Bash, `dash`, etc:

```
#!/bin/sh
seq 20 |       # make a long list
grep '[234]'   # mut only take part of it
```

Similarly with `&&` or `||` in place of the pipe, and also inside `$( ... )`.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that makes your command have invalid syntax is the fact that you needlessly escape the newlines on each line.

Your command,

```
gateway=$(cat $leases \
            | grep -A 5 -m 1 $wifi \
            | grep option\ routers \
            | cut -d' ' -f5 \
            | tr --delete \;)
```

is identical to

```
gateway=$(cat $leases | grep -A 5 -m 1 $wifi | grep option\ routers  | cut -d' ' -f5 | tr --delete \;)
```

In other words, from the shell's point of view, it's not a multi-line command at all.

Inserting a comment into this before the `cut` makes the command substitution unterminated (the final `)` is commended out):

```
gateway=$(cat $leases | grep -A 5 -m 1 $wifi | grep option\ routers  # Here is a note | cut -d' ' -f5 | tr --delete \;)
```

However, there is no need to escape the newlines.  The following is totally valid code:

```
gateway=$(cat $leases
            | grep -A 5 -m 1 $wifi
            | grep option\ routers
            | cut -d' ' -f5
            | tr --delete \;)
```

Here, it's just fine to insert a comment:

```
gateway=$(cat $leases
            | grep -A 5 -m 1 $wifi
            | grep option\ routers
            # Here is a note
            | cut -d' ' -f5
            | tr --delete \;)
```

It's fine to do this because each part of a pipeline may be followed by one or several newlines, and a comment is ignored by the shell's parser.

---

Looking at the actual *code*, this is a safer and more portable variant (except for the initial `grep` that still requires using non-standard extensions):

```
gateway=$(grep -A 5 -m 1 -e "$wifi" <"$leases"
            | grep -F 'option routers'
            # Here is a note
            | cut -d ' ' -f 5
            | tr -d ';' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, `zsh`, which can emulate bash (just call it as bash or run `emulate bash`), actually supports **multi-line commands**!

Just run `bindkey -e` or `bindkey "^[^M" self-insert-unmeta`, and then you can go to a new line by hitting M-Return.

It is saved as one history entry; you can move around with the arrow keys as you would expect. It will only switch entries when you go up/down at the top/bottom row.